# How to form a range on a concatenated string array in SSRS report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, expression, reporting, ssrs-tablix

The data is in separate rows in SQL DB. It has been grouped and then concatenated to get the table in this format. However, I need to form a range for the Maturity Value.

I have tried few ideas like:
=IIF(Fields!Pivot_2.Value.Contains(" Years"), "30 Years", Nothing)

and using Calculated Fields in Dataset Properties like:
=Split(Fields!Pivot_2.Value,",")(0)

However not sure how to expand on it to get a range for this cell.

Desired output: Grab the biggest in years and smallest in days. If days are not there then smallest in months. Something like 30 Years - 1 Day.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following custom code

```
Public Function ParsePeriods(ByVal str As String) As String

Dim iMin As Integer = 1000000
Dim iMax As Integer = -1

Dim sMin As String = ""
Dim sMax As String = ""

' Replace text with numbers to make it comparable
str = Replace(str, " years", "0000")
str = Replace(str, " year", "0000")
str = Replace(str, " months", "00")
str = Replace(str, " month", "00")
str = Replace(str, " days", "")
str = Replace(str, " day", "")

' Split string elements and loop to get the min and max values
Dim strArr() As String = str.Split(",")

For Each element As String In strArr

If Cint(element) < iMin Then
iMin = Cint(element)
End If

If Cint(element) > iMax Then
iMax = Cint(element)
End If

Next


' Use the integer min and max values to create min and max strings
If iMin < 100 Then
sMin = Cstr(iMin) & " day(s)"
ElseIf iMin < 10000
sMin = Cstr(iMin/100) & " month(s)"
Else 
sMin = Cstr(iMin/10000) & " year(s)"
End If

If iMax < 100 Then
sMax = Cstr(iMax) & " day(s)"
ElseIf iMax < 10000
sMax = Cstr(iMax/100) & " month(s)"
Else 
sMax = Cstr(iMax/10000) & " year(s)"
End If

Return Cstr(sMin) & " - " & Cstr(sMax)

End Function
```

Now you can use an expression like the one below to call the custom code

```
= Code.ParsePeriods( ReportItems!MaturityValue.Value )
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

You can apply a similar logic for SP rating

```
Public Function ParseSPrating(ByVal str As String) As String

Dim sMin As String = "111111111"
Dim sMax As String = "-1"

str = Replace(str, " ", "")
str = Replace(str, "A", "9")
str = Replace(str, "B", "8")
str = Replace(str, "C", "7")
str = Replace(str, "D", "6")
str = Replace(str, "+", "2")
str = Replace(str, "-", "0")

Dim strArr() As String = str.Split(",")

For Each element As String In strArr

If Cint( Left(element & "1111",4) ) < CInt(sMin) Then
sMin = Left(element & "1111",4)
End If

If Cint( Left(element & "1111",4) ) > CInt(sMax) Then
sMax = Left(element & "1111",4)
End If

Next

sMin = Replace(sMin, "9", "A")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "8", "B")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "7", "C")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "6", "D")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "2", "+")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "0", "-")
sMin = Replace(sMin, "1", "")

sMax = Replace(sMax, "9", "A")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "8", "B")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "7", "C")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "6", "D")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "2", "+")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "0", "-")
sMax = Replace(sMax, "1", "")

Return sMax & " - " & sMin

End Function
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. This was super helpful. Share your thoughts on how to enhance it if say we have also values like "30+ Years" and "<1Day". I mean the symbol "+" or "<" being used.

Comment: You are welcome. If these are standards you can by default set the as min or max. You can use the solution as guide to your problem

Comment: @BellFrajer , If you found niktrs's answer was useful you should mark it as accepted, this question no longer appears unanswered. If you then need more info you should start a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan. I did that now. New to community so learning.

Comment: @niktrs thanks, Also, in the same, if I have to create a range for the SP ratings?
For e.g in above, AAA to BBB would be the range. Desired output (AAA - BBB). These ratings can usually be anything between AAA to D.

Comment: I have updated my answer also for sp rating